# Same column value different rows to different column value different rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a table below like below

```
Column a                         Column b
------------------------------------------
aaaa                              13     
aaaa                              22     
aaaa                               3     
aaaa                              23    
bbbb                              44    
bbbb                              56    
bbbb                               9     
bbbb                               0
```

I want to take data from one table and put it into another table but I want to make on of the columns unique as it is not unique

I am trying to come up with the SQL statement

```
DECLARE @Count INT 
SET @count = 4

case when @count <= 4 then
while @Count = @Count - 1 and @Count <> 0
select @Count + columnA, columnBform tablename
```

After executing a query I want the data to display as below

```
Column a                         Column b
------------------------------------------
1aaaa                              13     
2aaaa                              22     
3aaaa                               3     
4aaaa                              23    
1bbbb                              44    
2bbbb                              56    
3bbbb                               9     
4bbbb                               0
```

Comment: Have you looked to `ROW_NUMBER()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do it using a window function `ROW_NUMBER` as

```
SELECT CONCAT(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY Col1), Col1) Col1,
       Col2
FROM
(
  VALUES
  ('aaaa',                              13),     
  ('aaaa',                              22),     
  ('aaaa',                              3 ),    
  ('aaaa',                              23),    
  ('bbbb',                              44),    
  ('bbbb',                              56),    
  ('bbbb',                              9 ),    
  ('bbbb',                              0 )
) T(Col1, Col2)
```

<kbd>**[`Online Demo`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cff4d52f31bf6340ec80f708d2b31ea2)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT
    CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY column_a ORDER BY column_b) AS VARCHAR(5))
        + column_a,
    column_b
FROM mytable
```

This will assign increasing numbers in each group of records sharing the sahme `column_a`, by ascending `column_b`. You can use another column to order the records if that's more revelant for you.